# VBA Sendkeys loop for print options

Tags: vba, loops, windows-7, excel-2010, sendkeys

Update: @Blackhawk provided me with the piece of information I needed to answer the question - scroll to the bottom for a working solution.

We've had some annoying new print software installed on our systems which requires me to select each worksheet in an Excel workbook and set the print options (i.e. landscape, page size, collate preference, colour etc) on it separately.

Support seems to think this is perfectly acceptable, and aren't much help.  There are two work arounds that I've found, one is to save the selected sheets as a `.pdf` and then print (only needing to select print options once) and the other is to use `sendkeys`.  From reading, I can see that `sendkeys` are not a good choice, so if I have to go the `.pdf` route I will, but this is definitely not ideal, as my end users prefer `.xls` files (because it means they can filter data etc.)

Because of that, I've written some VBA that will currently allow me to quickly set print options for one worksheet in excel:

```
Sub A00_Sendkeystest()
'

Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))

Application.SendKeys ("%p"), True 'Selects Page Layout
Application.SendKeys ("%i"), True 'Selects Print Titles
Application.SendKeys ("%o"), True 'Selects Options
Application.SendKeys ("%f"), True 'Selects profile
Application.SendKeys ("l"), True  'Selects 'Landscape' default (this needs to be set up initially)
Application.SendKeys "{TAB 14}", True 'Tabs to OK
Application.SendKeys "~", True 'Hits enter to close screen
Application.SendKeys "{TAB 11}", True 'Tabs to OK
Application.SendKeys "~", True 'Hits enter to close screen

End Sub
```

This runs quite nicely when assigned to a shortcut, so I can run it quite quickly against one sheet in a workbook.

However, what I'd really like to do is write the VBA to loop through the sheets I've selected for printing and run the `sendkeys` code against each worksheet.  I've tried the following:

```
Sub cycle()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets

    ws.Activate

    'Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:10"))

    Application.SendKeys ("%p") ', True 'Selects Page Layout
    Application.SendKeys ("%i") ', True 'Selects Print Titles
    Application.SendKeys ("%o") ', True 'Selects Options
    Application.SendKeys ("%f") ', True 'Selects profile
    Application.SendKeys ("l") ', True  'Selects 'Landscape' default (this needs to be set up initially)
    Application.SendKeys "{TAB 14}" ', True 'Tabs to OK
    Application.SendKeys "~" ', True 'Hits enter to close screen
    Application.SendKeys "{TAB 11}" ', True 'Tabs to OK
    Application.SendKeys "~" ', True 'Hits enter to close screen

    Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:03"))

    Next

End Sub
```

However, when watching the macro run, it cycles through each page and then just as the macro ends, it appears to try to execute the `sendkeys` section 4 times (which doesn't work of course).

I've tried building in a delay but it's literally like the `application.sendkeys` part of the code only executes just before the macro ends.

I'm using Office 2010 with Windows 7, but any suggestions on how to get this to work (or any alternative ideas!) would be much appreciated.  Thanks

Final code:

```
Sub cycle()

'Macro will cycle through selected sheets and select landscape_printing profile in print options.

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets

    ws.Activate

    Application.SendKeys ("%p"), True 'Selects Page Layout
    Application.SendKeys ("%i"), True 'Selects Print Titles
    Application.SendKeys ("%o"), True 'Selects Options
    Application.SendKeys ("%f"), True 'Selects profile
    Application.SendKeys ("l"), True  'Selects 'Landscape' default (this needs to be set up initially)
    Application.SendKeys "{TAB 14}", True 'Tabs to OK
    Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
    Application.SendKeys "~", True 'Hits enter to close screen
    Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
    Application.SendKeys "~", True 'Hits enter to close screen

    DoEvents

    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "Completed."

End Sub
```

Comment: Also the first two sendkeys lines can be replaced by this single line `Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PrintTitles")`

Comment: @SiddharthRout thanks for this, I can see it works, but for some reason when using this the rest of my macro doesn't quite run in the manner I want it to, so I've left it out for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try throwing an `DoEvents` in there, right before the `Application.Wait`.  I suspect that Excel needs a moment to process those keypresses as OS events.

Every windows application has a message queue, to which Windows sends appropriate event messages to notify it of things like the user clicking or pressing keys.  My guess is that Excel is continuously running your code (even the Wait) and doesn't have a chance to process the keypresses, so the messages that Windows sends to Excel just queue up.  When it finishes running the macro, it turns to handling all the queued up messages and handles them.

Adding a [DoEvents](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/118468) tells Excel to process any messages currently in its queue (or some portion of them, not quite sure on that point), which means running your keypresses and printing the sheet.

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick.  Thank you both for the answer and the explanation.  I've posted my amended VBA as I had to make some tweaks as with the doevents added it wasn't closing the option/print titles screen down. I tried using the application.commandbars line but it was throwing the macro so I stuck with the first two sendkeys. Cheers!