# How to set Paper Type in Word using MS Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, ms-word, vba

I am opening a document in Word (using VBA in Access) and then I do some find and replace on the text to update the date etc. Then I set the printer tray(s) and send to the printer (PrintOut).

This part works great, however the client has a Konica Minolta printer and when we send the document to TrayX it mysteriously decides to make the paper type "Letterhead" at which point the printer prints on the *back* of the paper (huh??). It seems to be a quirk of the printer but the fix to the quirk is to print with the paper type of "Plain Paper". 
So me thinks I will just set the paper type before calling "PrintOut", except I cannot find any way to set the paper type! I can spec out just about every other setting but not the paper type.

Any ideas, what am I missing?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no direct way to set the `Paper Type`. An alternative could be to use `SendKeys` as shown [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20102732/vba-sendkeys-loop-for-print-options)

Comment: Ouch send keys...not my favorite way of coding automation, might have to do it if I can't find a way to set correctly on computer.

Comment: There is some code that shows how to interface to the Win32 printer API at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197339.aspx (could even be some questions here on SO about it - I haven't looked)

Comment: I am using some of that code to retrieve the paper bins. I am afraid that the paper names will only contain the paper sizes, but I will test it and see what I get.

Comment: bibadia, That is a great link, however it doesn't get the paper types such as "Plain Paper", Letterhead, transperancy. Instead I get Letter, Legal, Statement, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to set the paper type at the time of printing. It turns out that the Konica driver prints to the "back" of the First Page Tray when you have Word set to print the first page to Tray (X) and the Other Pages to Tray (Y).

Ultimately the client wanted to print duplex which means in order to print the first 2 pages to the letterhead we need to make 2 Application.PrintOut function calls: 1 for page 1-2 to Tray X and another for 3 and up to Tray Y.

So the final answer was to make 2 calls like this:

```
    oDoc.PageSetup.FirstPageTray = CLng(rstDocs!intCofAWordTraySetting)
    oDoc.PageSetup.OtherPagesTray = CLng(rstDocs!intCofAWordTraySetting)
    oDoc.PrintOut Copies:=CInt(rstDocs!intCopies), Pages:="1-2"
```